# popup  div when hover over radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have three radio button options:

- None
- Float Left
- Float Right

so when the user mouseover/hover over the radio button i just want to preview the div.

```
<asp:radiobuttonlist runat="server" id="rbl" repeatdirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:listitem text="None" value="0" selected="True" enabled="true"/>
    <asp:listitem text="Float Left" value="1" selected="False" enabled="true"/>
    <asp:listitem text="Float Right" value="2" selected="False" enabled="true"/>
</asp:radiobuttonlist>
```

here is the div:

```
<div id="divid">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam non justo at est sodales molestie vitae id ligula. Proin sed consequat augue. Donec neque nibh, laoreet vel laoreet non, dignissim id lectus. Maecenas pulvinar pretium leo, quis pharetra odio pulvinar at. Integer tincidunt orci eget velit consectetur suscipit. Nullam in augue ut felis volutpat cursus. In mi augue, accumsan vel laoreet nec, scelerisque vitae nibh. Sed quis dolor quam, nec rhoncus lorem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras varius luctus nulla vel dapibus. Donec aliquam vehicula tincidunt. Suspendisse potenti. Donec at odio lorem. Nam aliquam rhoncus aliquam. Sed posuere tincidunt purus non tristique.
</div>
```

Comment: This makes very little sense. Can you rewrite the question?

Comment: just update my question, make sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#<%= rbl.ClientID %>:radio').hover(
    function (){ 
        $('#divid').toggle();
    },
    function (){ 
        $('#divid').toggle();
    }
);
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/awqAm/)

[demo using ui dialog](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/2VcWp/)

[new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/jnUE4/) seems to be trouble with closing dialog so I commented it out for now

Comment: Hard to answer question from iPhone

Comment: I reformatted it for you, and added asp code which will insert the proper ID name for that control.

Comment: @Abu Hamzah happy to help now that I'm at my computer I fixed the code to look the way intended

Comment: when i hover over the `radiobutton` what i want is to popup the div but your sample does not do anything, when the page loads i see the div showing but what i want is when the hover/mouse over over the radiobutton then only i want to poup the div.

Comment: thanks for the fiddle, how can i popup the div instead of just displaying inline?

Comment: i updated my question, when i try to implement on .html file and it does not do anything, i see the block is visible when the page loads and when i try to hover other radio button does not do anything, can you see my code what i am missing?

Comment: okay i download but my code still does not work, the only difference i see in the code is your radiobutton control is different then what i have in my post, please look at my `<asp:radiobuttonlist`

Comment: i don't see where your giving it the type= "radio" in your asp .. please bare with as I don't know a thing about asp if you show the generated source that may help me to help you

Comment: one last question (if you want i can open a another thread) the question is, i have three div boxes and three radio button, how can i show each radiobutton has own div ? like if i hover on radiobutton 1 then i want to show div1 and ......rb2 then div 2 ....

Comment: how can i write a title on a ui dialog box?

Comment: to add title add to options $('#divid').dialog({title:"some title"});

Comment: i updated my question, its not working if i try your sample, pls have a look, sorry its taking long.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
$("input[name='<%= rbl.ClientID %>']").hover(
       function() { $("#divid").toggle(); }
);
```

Something along these lines: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/MfRKu/).

Comment: i just updated my question, update: popup preview, when hover/mouseover i want to show as a popup preview

Answer (score 0):

Does this fulfill your requirement?

```
$(":radio[name='rbl']").hover(function(){ 
    $("#divid").css({
        display: "block",
        position: "absolute",
        left: ($(this).offset().left + $(this).width()) + "px",
        top: $(this).offset().top + "px"
    });
},
function(){
     $("#divid").hide();   
});
```

Comment: did not work, does not show anything when i hover or click on the radiobutton